# Help plz with Technics

Tags: help

Мой МФУ HP2520 перестал адекватно печатать, я так поняла это из-за того, что в МФУ двойная система контроля чернил и после перезаправки картриджа, обнулить картридж заклейкой контактов никак нельзя. Может быть есть какой-то другой способ снова привести его в строй? (Главная проблема в том, что бОльшую часть времени МФУ не печатает жёлтым). 
Да, странное место для таких вопросов.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about HP printers and has nothing to do with Tor.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the place for printer conversation. Try the following:
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/

---

Это не место для разговора о принтере. Попробуйте следующее
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/